# Can't bind winsock socket

Tags: c++, networking, winsock, winsock2

I'm quite new to c++ networking so I've been watching some tutorials but I can't seem to find out why I can't bind my socket. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code for binding the socket.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment (lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning( disable : 4996)
#define PORT 17027
int main()
{
    //creating socket
    SOCKET listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    //bind socket
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    int bindValue = bind(listenSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    if (bindValue == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl; 
        return 1;
    }
```

Output: Could not bind: 10038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must state which interface you want to bind the socket to. This is done by setting the `sin_addr` member of the `sockaddr_in` structure.

For example, to bind to the wildcard interface `INADDR_ANY` (to be able to receive connections from all interfaces), you would do something like this:

```
address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

Whereas to bind to a specific interface, you would do something like this:

```
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("interface IP here");
```

---

Regarding the error reporting, the Winsock API doesn't set `errno` for error (and `errno` is used by `perror()`). Instead, you need to use [`WSAGetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror) to get the error code, and [`FormatMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) to get the error description.

Comment: I just tried to add the "address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);" part and changed the perror part to WSAGetLastError but it still doesn't work and I get no error.

Comment: @ReaperB_G Do you print the result of `WSAGetLAstError()`? Like `if (bindValue == SOCKET_ERROR) { std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << '\n'; return 1; }`

Comment: Yea I was colling the error function wrong. But now I'm getting error 10038.

Comment: @ReaperB_G If you follow the documentation I linked to, and follow it to the [error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) you will see that `10038` means `WSAENOTSOCK` which is "Socket operation on nonsocket." Did the `socket` call succeed? Have you checked that? I'll bet it didn't succeed because you forgot to call the [`WSAStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) function. Remember to always check for error for ***all*** functions.

Comment: Ok i added the WSAStartup function and called the socket setup after that and that fixed It thanks for your help.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude note that in the OP's original code, `INADDR_ANY` is defined as `0` (aka `0.0.0.0`), so the call to `memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address))` was already implicitly setting `sin_addr.s_addr` to `INADDR_ANY`.

Answer (score 3):

Error `10038` is `WSAENOTSOCK` ("Socket operation on nonsocket"), which means you are calling `bind()` on an invalid `SOCKET`.  And indeed, you are not checking if `socket()` is successful.  Which it is not, as you are not calling [`WSAStartup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) first, so `socket()` is failing with a `WSANOTINITIALISED` error ("Successful WSAStartup not yet performed").

> The WSAStartup function must be the first Windows Sockets function called by an application or DLL. It allows an application or DLL to specify the version of Windows Sockets required and retrieve details of the specific Windows Sockets implementation. **The application or DLL can only issue further Windows Sockets functions after successfully calling WSAStartup.**

Comment: One of the things that you should take away from this answer is always check the return code and make sure you understand what the value returned implies. In network programming you have to be religious with return codes because they are rarely just worked/failed. `recv`, for example, tells you how much data was read (which isn't always the amount of data asked for) or that the socket disconnected politely or that an error occurred and you'll have to make another call to `WSAGetLAstError` to find out what that error was.